# Oracle 10g Select records that satisfy a certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'd appreciate some help with following query.. I have a table as below,

```
UID | Status | Msg_Id | Msg_Id_type
1   | START  | AA     | GLOBAL
2   | END    | AA     | GLOBAL
3   | PROC   | AA     | GLOBAL
4   | START  | BB     | GLOBAL
5   | START  | CC     | GLOBAL
6   | START  | DD     | GLOBAL
7   | END    | DD     | GLOBAL
```

What I'd like to achieve is SELECT only those records, that do not have any other STATUS than "START" for a given MSG_ID or all records that do not have any other STATUS except "START". Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Please provide desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: 4 | START | BB | GLOBAL|<br/>5 | START | CC | GLOBAL|<br/> Since these are the only records that do not have any other statuses except "START". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all msg_ids that have only START as their status.

```
select msg_id
from the_table
where msg_id in (select msg_id from the_table where status = 'START')
group by msg_id
having count(distinct status) = 1
```

Comment: Hi Horse, I just ran the query above, but not getting any results

Comment: My apologies. It was a data issue that caused the query to return no results. It works. Thanks everyone for the response..

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM my_table b
        WHERE b.status <> 'START'
            AND b.msg_id = a.msg_id
    )
    AND a.status = 'START' -- < I think you can ignore this line.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
SELECT msg_id  
  FROM TABLE  
 GROUP by msg_id  
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'START' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1  
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS <> 'START' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0
```

`